# Secure size-limited backups to a cPanel-controlled website

Tags: backup, ftp, sftp, cpanel

So I've just got a new computer and want to start doing the "right thing" with automatic backups. I've got a website (shared hosting, managed via cPanel), so the extra space on my server seems like a natural place to put the backup.

Based on a bit of poking around the internet, I can figure out how to do secure backups (connect via https://example.com:2078) [[1]](https://blog.bigwetfish.hosting/cpanel-web-disk/), and how to size-limited backups (connect via ftp://example.com) [[2]](http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-map-a-ftp-to-a-drive-in-windows/), but not how to make a connection that is both secure *and* size-limited. The first option is secure via SSL, but has no ability to set a size quota. The second can set size quotas, but using FTP is apparently a security vulnerability, at least so I'm told.

How can I make backups that are both secure and size-limited?

I've tried and failed to augment option 1, by additionally limiting the size of the backups folder on the server. It seems the only way to limit a folder size is by creating a filesystem myself [[3]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841282/how-to-set-a-file-size-limit-for-a-directory), but that requires root access. Which I don't have on a shared plan.

Likewise the obvious augmentation to option 2 is to use SFTP. But that doesn't seem to be an option through cPanel like FTP is, and thus doesn't have an option to specify a size quota.

I'm expecting that this is straightforward if you know what you're doing, but I'm still a relative novice to this end of things.

Comment: I don't think you have thought this through.  What happens when the size of your backup exceeds your quota size?   Surely you are better off doing uploads and putting a system in place to monitor when you are running low on disk space ,or backups are becoming to large?

Comment: Then the backup should fail. I'd just much rather the backup fails than my emails (on the same server) fail due to running out of room.

I considered just adding a warning system on a cronjob or similar, but the problem then is if the to-backup folder jumps upward in size (rather than just generally drifting upwards in size), then a warning system is too late to be useful.